# Opening VS with Python blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio, subprocess

I am trying to open Visual Studio from a python script without blocking the script. My understanding is that both subprocess.Popen and os.system are non-blocking. However, both of these block when opening Visual Studio:

```py
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\VS2017\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe MySolution.sln', cwd=get_build_dir(command))
```

and

```py
os.system(r'C:\VS2017\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe MySolution.sln')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html)

Comment: seems cool, but i'm on Python 2.7

Comment: Twisted https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/